# vslam eigen and compile_error

Tags: ros, vslam, eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to compile vslam as instructed but halting at some error mentioned below:

Is there anything that i am suppose to make link to eigen3 externally?

> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosnode
> ROS_NOBUILD in package rosnode
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>>
> image_transport [ make ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<<
> image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package
> image_transport
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> cv_bridge [
> make ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< cv_bridge
> ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>>
> image_geometry [ make ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<<
> image_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package
> image_geometry
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make
> ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosmsg
> ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg  No
> Makefile in package rosmsg
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosservice [
> make ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosservice
> ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> roswtf [ make
> ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< roswtf
> ROS_NOBUILD in package roswtf
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf [ make ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf
> ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> nav_msgs [
> make ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< nav_msgs
> ROS_NOBUILD in package nav_msgs
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>>
> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<<
> dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in
> package dynamic_reconfigure
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> stereo_msgs [
> make ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< stereo_msgs
> ROS_NOBUILD in package stereo_msgs
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< bpcg [PASS] [
> 1.40 seconds ]                                                                                                                   [rosmake-1] Finished <<<
> vocabulary_tree [PASS] [ 1.51 seconds
> ]
> [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesame_common:
> 3.5 sec ]                                                                                               [ 1 Active 51/54 Complete ]
> {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------   /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:206:
> error: ‘SelfAdjoint’ was not declared
> in this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:206:
> error: ‘Upper’ was not declared in
> this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:206:
> error: template argument 3 is invalid
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:212:
> error: ‘SelfAdjoint’ was not declared
> in this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:212:
> error: ‘Lower’ was not declared in
> this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:212:
> error: template argument 3 is invalid
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:231:
> error: ‘SelfAdjoint’ was not declared
> in this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:231:
> error: ‘Lower’ was not declared in
> this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:231:
> error: template argument 3 is invalid
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:237:
> error: ‘SelfAdjoint’ was not declared
> in this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:237:
> error: ‘Upper’ was not declared in
> this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:237:
> error: ‘Dynamic’ was not declared in
> this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:237:
> error: template argument 3 is invalid
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:237:
> error: template argument 4 is invalid
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:255:
> error: ‘SelfAdjoint’ was not declared
> in this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:255:
> error: ‘Lower’ was not declared in
> this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:255:
> error: ‘Dynamic’ was not declared in
> this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:255:
> error: template argument 3 is invalid
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:255:
> error: template argument 4 is invalid
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:278:
> error: no ‘const
> Eigen3::SelfAdjointView<Derived, UpLo>
> Eigen3::MatrixBase::selfadjointView()
> const’ member function declared in
> class ‘Eigen3::MatrixBase’
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/SelfAdjointView.h:285:
> error: no
> ‘Eigen3::SelfAdjointView<Derived,
> UpLo>
> Eigen3::MatrixBase::selfadjointView()’
> member function declared in class
> ‘Eigen3::MatrixBase’   In
> file included from
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/Core:306,
> from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/point_cloud_perception/pcl/include/pcl/pcl_base.h:42,
> from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/point_cloud_perception/pcl/include/pcl/common/common.h:41,
> from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/vslam/frame_common/include/frame_common/frame.h:56,
> from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/vslam/frame_common/src/draw.cpp:40:
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/products/Parallelizer.h:29:
> error: variable or field
> ‘ei_manage_multi_threading’ declared
> void
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/products/Parallelizer.h:29:
> error: ‘Action’ was not declared in
> this scope
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/products/Parallelizer.h:29:
> error: expected primary-expression
> before ‘int’
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/products/Parallelizer.h:128:
> error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
> /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/geometry_experimental/eigen3/include/Eigen3/src/Core/products/Parallelizer.h:128:
> error: expected declaration before end
> of line   make[3]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/frame_common.dir/src/frame.o]
> Error 1   make[3]: *** Waiting for
> unfinished jobs....   make[3]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/frame_common.dir/src/draw.o]
> Error 1   make[3]: Leaving directory
> `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/vslam/frame_common/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/frame_common.dir/all] Error 2   make[2]: Leaving directory` /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/vslam/frame_common/build'
> make[1]: *** [all] Error 2   make[1]:
> Leaving directory
> `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/vslam/frame_common/build'
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------} [ rosmake ] Output from build of
> package frame_common written to: [
> rosmake ]
> /home/rootx/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110216-104646/frame_common/build_output.log
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< frame_common
> [FAIL] [ 3.52 seconds ]
> [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in
> package frame_common. [ rosmake ]
> Waiting for other threads to complete.
> [ rosmake ] Results:
> [ rosmake ] Built 52 packages with 1
> failures.
> [ rosmake ] Summary output to
> directory
> [ rosmake ]
> /home/rootx/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110216-104646

Any help appreciated.

Prasad

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9084/vslam-eigen-and-compile_error/) by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-16**:
Could you specify what instructions you are following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

changed  Eigen3 to Eigen in all the following files,
freiburg_kinect-experimental/rgbdslam/manifest
freiburg_kinect-experimental/rgbdslam/src/ node openni_listerer graph_manager

They have made changes recently.

---

Originally posted by [Bruce](https://answers.ros.org/users/224/bruce/) with karma: 26 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1